# Recursion with array's PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have a function (listarUrls ()) that returns / scans all the urls it finds on a web page.
I need that for each of the urls that the function returns to me, I return to the list / scan all the urls of that page
many times as requested by the user, that is

```
        .If the user asks for 1 iteration of the url www.a.com, bring back:
            -$arry[0] www.1.com
            -$arry[1] www.2.com
            -..... So with all the urls you find in www.a.com

        .If the user asks for 2 iteration of the url www.a.com, bring back:
            -$arry[0] www.1.com
                -$arry[0][0] www.1-1.com
                -$arry[0][1] www.1-2.com
                -...So with all the urls you find in www.1.com
            -$arry[1] www.2.com
                -$arry[1][0] www.2-1.com
                -$arry[1][1] www.2-2.com
                -...So with all the urls you find in www.2.com
            -...

        .If the user asks for 3 iteration of the url www.a.com, bring back:
            -$arry[0] www.1.com
                -$arry[0][0] www.1-1.com
                    -$arry[0][0][0] www.1-1-1.com
                    -$arry[0][0][1] www.1-1-2.com
                    -...So with all the urls you find in www.1-1.com
                -$arry[0][1] www.1-2.com
                    -$arry[0][1][0] www.1-2-1.com
                    -$arry[0][1][1] www.1-2-2.com
                    -...So with all the urls you find in www.1-2.com
            -$arry[1] www.2.com
                -$arry[1][0] www.2-1.com
                    -$arry[1][0][0] www.2-1-1.com
                    -$arry[1][0][1] www.2-1-2.com
                    -...So with all the urls you find in www.2-1.com
                -$arry[1][1] www.2-2.com
                    -$arry[1][1][0] www.2-2-1.com
                    -$arry[1][1][1] www.2-2-2.com
                    -...So with all the urls you find in www.2-2.com
        -...
```

Could someone shed some light on the subject please?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to create the array recursively with the urls of each web depending on the number of iterations that the user requests.

Comment: You don't have to create the array recursively.  You have to iterate recursively and return results.

Comment: You could give me an example of the function that I must create please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is web scraping with the option to instruct how much deep to investigate.

We can have a function definition like below:

```
function scrapeURLs($url,$steps,&$visited_urls = []);
```

Here, `$url` is the current URL we are scraping. `$steps` is which step we are investigating. If `$steps == 1` at any point in our recursive function, we stop scraping further. `$visited_urls` is to make sure we aren't visiting same URL twice for scraping.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time','500');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // not recommended but fine for debugging. Make sure HTML of the URL follows DOMDocument requirements
function scrapeURLs($url,$steps,&$visited_urls = []){
    $result = [];   
    if(preg_match('/^http(s)?:\/\/.+/',$url) === 0){ // if not a proper URL, we stop here, but will have to double check if it's a relative URL and do some modifications to current script
        return $result;
    }

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

    // get all script tags
    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('script') as $script_tag){
        $script_url = $script_tag->getAttribute('src');
        if(!isset($visited_urls[$script_url])){
            $visited_urls[$script_url] = true;
            $result[$script_url] = $steps === 1 ? [] : scrapeURLs($script_url,$steps - 1,$visited_urls);    // stop or recurse further  
        }       

    }   

    // get all anchor tags
    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $anchor_tag){
        $anchor_url = $anchor_tag->getAttribute('href');
        if(!isset($visited_urls[$anchor_url])){
            $visited_urls[$anchor_url] = true;
            $result[$anchor_url] = $steps === 1 ? [] : scrapeURLs($anchor_url,$steps - 1,$visited_urls);
            // stop or recurse further
        }
    }

    /* Likewise, you can capture several other URLs like CSS stylesheets, image URLs etc*/

    return $result;
}

print_r(scrapeURLs('http://yoursite.com/',2));
```

Comment: perfect, thank you very much vivek_23

Comment: @In0cybe Glad to help :) I hope you followed the steps and this gave you correct results for different depths.

Answer (score 0):

array_walk_recursive — Apply a user function recursively to every member of an array
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Comment: Thanks K IV but how could I make a function that will create the array with all recursive levels as requested by the user?